# retrieve a second option of a table

Tags: c#, sql, database, ado.net

I'm developping an application with C# and ADO.Net entity data model. I have a table Users in SQL Server database with 3 columns (idUser, nameUser, statusUser).
What is the code to retrieve the second or the third or the Nth... user of the table that have statusUser = 0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, what we use for pagination etc..

```
using (soforumEntities ctx = new soforumEntities())
{
      Article a = ctx.Articles.Where(c => (c.ArticleStatus != null && c.ArticleStatus.HasValue && c.ArticleStatus.Value != true)).OrderBy(x => x.ArticleStatus).Skip(1).Take(1).SingleOrDefault();
            Console.WriteLine(a.Id + a.Name);
}
```

Comment: The Skip method is only supported for sorted input in LINQ to Entities. The OrderBy method must be called before the Skip method.

Comment: @NaourassDerouichi: Can you sort by any field, or else try to order by `db.Articles.Where(x=>x.ArticleStatus != false || x.ArticleStatus !=0).OrderBy(c=>c.ArticleStatus).Skip(1).Take(1).SingleOrDefault();`

Comment: can you please let us know what is the datatype of the `ArticleStatus` property. Fixing the order by property alone will give you the solution you intend

Comment: @NaourassDerouichi: Sorry for the delay and confusions. I have updated the solution after checking with data from the db as per your specifications. Please try this and post the update.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [DENSE_RANK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) function.